# Association, Belongs_to, and Ownership for 4-table Database

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm building an app that has one 'master user' through devise. This master user creates records of employees and items that we're tracking. When a user wants to 'checkout a item', he'll send a text to a twilio phone number and that'll create a new 'transaction' of that item, either checking it in or checking it out. So I have three tables - 'employees', 'items', and 'transactions'. Plan is to intercept these incoming texts, parse the phone number that it comes from, the item they're texting about, and the code that they give, i.e. 'CI 12345' would 'Check In Item 12345', etc. Anyway, I'm scaffolding this stuff up just to make sure that I can make these transactions within the web app by hand before I start messing with an API to create transaction records, but I'm having a hard time associating the transactions with the items (and/or users). A transaction would need to have a boolean 'in/out' value, a phone number to match it up with the employee that is performing the action, and then an item number to associate it with an item being tracked. I keep getting errors saying that I don't have a method defined for 'transactions' when trying to load up a 'transaction show view', so to speak. I'm not sure what's going on here. Kinda new to all this, this is only my second app.

db/schema.rb

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130515114928) do

      create_table "employees", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "phone"
        t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
      end

      create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "assettag"
        t.string   "description"
        t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
      end

      create_table "transactions", :force => true do |t|
        t.boolean  "status"
        t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
        t.integer  "item_id"
        t.string   "empphone"
      end

      add_index "transactions", ["item_id"], :name => "index_transactions_on_item_id"

      create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
      end

      add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
      add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

    end
```

app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb

```
    class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
      # GET /transactions
      # GET /transactions.json
      def index
        @transactions = Transaction.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @transactions }
        end
      end

      # GET /transactions/1
      # GET /transactions/1.json
      def show
        @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
        @description = transaction.item.description

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @transaction }
        end
      end

      # GET /transactions/new
      # GET /transactions/new.json
      def new
        @transaction = Transaction.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @transaction }
        end
      end

      # GET /transactions/1/edit
      def edit
        @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /transactions
      # POST /transactions.json
      def create
        @transaction = Transaction.new(params[:transaction])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @transaction.save
            format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: 'Transaction was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @transaction, status: :created, location: @transaction }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PUT /transactions/1
      # PUT /transactions/1.json
      def update
        @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @transaction.update_attributes(params[:transaction])
            format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: 'Transaction was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: "edit" }
            format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /transactions/1
      # DELETE /transactions/1.json
      def destroy
        @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
        @transaction.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to transactions_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end
    end
```

app/models/item.rb

```
    class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :assettag, :description
      validates :assettag, presence: true
      validates :description, presence: true

      has_many :transactions
    end
```

app/models/employee.rb

```
    class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :phone
      validates :phone, presence: true
      validates :name, presence: true
    end
```

app/models/transaction.rb

```
    class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :status, :item_id

      belongs_to :item
      validates :item_id, presence: true

      delegate :description, to: :item
    end
```

app/controllers/employees_controller.rb

```
    class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
      # GET /employees
      # GET /employees.json
      def index
        @employees = Employee.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @employees }
        end
      end

      # GET /employees/1
      # GET /employees/1.json
      def show
        @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @employee }
        end
      end

      # GET /employees/new
      # GET /employees/new.json
      def new
        @employee = Employee.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @employee }
        end
      end

      # GET /employees/1/edit
      def edit
        @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /employees
      # POST /employees.json
      def create
        @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @employee.save
            format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @employee, status: :created, location: @employee }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PUT /employees/1
      # PUT /employees/1.json
      def update
        @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @employee.update_attributes(params[:employee])
            format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: "edit" }
            format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /employees/1
      # DELETE /employees/1.json
      def destroy
        @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
        @employee.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to employees_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end
    end
```

app/controllers/items_controller.rb

```
    class ItemsController < ApplicationController
      # GET /items
      # GET /items.json
      def index
        @items = Item.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @items }
        end
      end

      # GET /items/1
      # GET /items/1.json
      def show
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @item }
        end
      end

      # GET /items/new
      # GET /items/new.json
      def new
        @item = Item.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @item }
        end
      end

      # GET /items/1/edit
      def edit
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /items
      # POST /items.json
      def create
        @item = Item.new(params[:item])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.save
            format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PUT /items/1
      # PUT /items/1.json
      def update
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
            format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: "edit" }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /items/1
      # DELETE /items/1.json
      def destroy
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        @item.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to items_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end
    end
```

app/views/transactions/show.html.erb

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

    <p>
      <b>Status:</b>
      <%= @transaction.status %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Description:</b>
      <%= transaction.description %>
    </p>


    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_transaction_path(@transaction) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', transactions_path %>
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in your view -- `transaction` (local variable) instead of `@transaction` (instance variable).

Comment: I'd tried it both ways, gave me same error regardless.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: NameError in TransactionsController#show

undefined local variable or method `transaction' for #<TransactionsController:0x007f8a28063d30>
Rails.root: /home/mike/Sites/tooler

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:17:in `show'

Answer (score 1):

In your transactions_controller.rb, delete the line where you assign the `@description` instance variable.

In your transactions/show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @transaction.description.presence || "No description" %>
</p>
```

Comment: put the @description = @transaction.item.description into the 'def show' of the controller, changed the show.html.erb, gave me this:

NoMethodError in TransactionsController#show

undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Check my updated answer. I think it's more adequate use a helper to handle displaying item descriptions in the view. What was happening is you were trying to call `description` when `item` was nil.

Comment: That seems to be a step in the right direction. The app doesn't crash now, but it keeps saying 'No Items Found', even though there is a description in place for this item. The transaction's item_id is '12345', and the item's assettag is '12345'. They should be matching up, but they're not.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice you're using `delegate` in the Transaction model. Let me update my answer.

Comment: So I should migrate the database to reflect that the index of the transactions table is assettag?

Comment: It doesn't seem that `assettag` is the primary key. I don't see the `:id => false` that should be there in schema.db. I believe you do have and id field. Keep in mind that it won't show up in schema.db even if it's there.

Comment: can I use self.primary_key = :assettag in the item model? or do I need to migrate the db?

Comment: You'd need to run a migration, yes.